# Why child class variable initialize before parent class member variable

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, initialization

Consider the code below. Fields `i` and `j` are initialized before `m` and `n`. We know that the parent object is created before the child object, but in my program the compiler is allocating and initializing memory for the child class' member variables before the base class'. Why is that?

```
class X
{
    private int m = 0;
    private int n = 90;
    public X() { }
}

class Y:X
{
    private int i = 8;
    private int j = 6;
    public Y()
    { }
    public static void Main(string []args)
    {
        Y y1 = new Y();  
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: i and j initialize before m and n, We know that parent object created first and than child object.But in my program  compiler allocating and initializing memory for child class member variables before Base class

Comment: "We know that the parent object is created before the child object" is not necessary true statement. `Y` is single object with 4 fields - so space for all 4 fields will be allocated at the same time. Order of initialization is covered in link in BartoszKP's +1 answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is explained in [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx):

> [...] an initialized readonly field is always observed in its initialized state, and we cannot make that guarantee unless we run all the initializers first, and then all of the constructor bodies.

Not sure why `readonly` is mentioned here, but for example, this ensures that the following scenarios, albeit being stupid, work:

1.

```
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        if (this is Derived) (this as Derived).Go();
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    X x = new X();

    public void Go()
    {
        x.DoSomething(); // !
    }
}
```

2.

```
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        Go();
    }

    public virtual Go() {}
}

class Derived : Base
{
    X x = new X();

    public override void Go()
    {
        x.DoSomething(); // !
    }
}
```

This order is explicitly stated in [C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) (17.10.2):

> [...] constructor implicitly performs the initializations specified by the variable-initializers of the instance fields declared in its class. This corresponds to a sequence of assignments that are executed immediately upon entry to the constructor and before the implicit invocation of the direct base class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Child construction code must be allowed to call functions on the parent, which can't work unless the parent is already fully-constructed.

However, the objects share the same memory block. So all the memory is allocated in one go, then the classes are initialized working up the class hierarchy.

Comment: But OP says that child fields are initialized before parent fields

Comment: @JuliánUrbano We're describing different relationships. There's a parent/child relationship between the classes and also between the objects.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. You're saying that the parent must be fully constructed for the child to call it's functions, meaning that the parent should be initialized first, right? The OP is saying it is the child who is initialized first.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those rare places where an understanding of procedural methodology makes object-oriented methodology easier to understand.  Even though you're working OOP, the compiler still adheres to procedural logic - working start to finish.

A simple example is when the compiler hits `private int n = 90`.  First it allocates space for an integer value, then an identifier to access it as an integer, then assigns it the value of 90.  It can't assign the value until it both has the space to stick it AND knows how to access it, nor can it access non-existent space.

In this instance, your derived class `Y` is built atop the base class `X`, similar to how the variable `n` is built atop the "class" `integer` in the example above.  This is triggered by the declaration `class Y:X` - the compiler can't even start building `Y` until it understands how to build `X`.